# Can one create Sized Types in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-systems

Is it possible to create types like e.g. `String(20)` in scala?

The aim would be to have compiler checks for things like:

```
a: String(20) 
b: String(30)
a = b; // throws a compiler exception when no implicit conversion is available
b= a; // works just fine
```

Note: It doesn't need to be/named  `String`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, using Church Numerals encoding. Jim McBeath has a good series of blogs relating to that. Start [here](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2008/11/practical-church-numerals-in-scala.html), but keep looking for other references on the Internet. He wasn't the only one to talk about it, nor was this his only post.

It isn't, however, very much practical.

Comment: Hopefully one day "real soon now" somebody will roll up their sleeves and write a Scala compiler plug-in to support "Refinement Types" in the Style of Sage http://sage.soe.ucsc.edu/ This will require integrating a latest-greatest theorem prover of course :-)